# how ther linux kernel process the write to /sys/power/state

Tags: linux, kernel, acpi, sysfs

I want to find out the source file of the Linux kernel (x86, 2.6.18 or similar) that handle the write to /sys/power/state.  I googled and try to search `sysfs_create_file` (and dir) in the source code. But I didn't find anything useful so far. Anyone knows that? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To find out where a call into the kernel ends up, [Ftrace](http://elinux.org/Ftrace) can be a handy tool.

For your particular case, I used the following command to get a function graph for a read from `/sys/power/state` (I figured the reading function wouldn't be too far away from writing function that you are looking for):

```
trace-cmd record -p function_graph -F cat /sys/power/state
```

(You need to be root to execute this)

This dumps the trace to a binary file called `trace.dat`. To read this file, do the following (again as root):

```
trace-cmd report
```

Then I used `grep` to filter the output on things like "power" or "state" and eventually was able to find the following (only showing relevant parts):

```
sysfs_read_file() {
  ...
  state_show() {
    valid_state() {
      acpi_suspend_state_valid();
    }
  }
  ...
}
```

So reading `/sys/power/state` ends up in [`state_show`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/kernel/power/main.c#L150). Below that function, you can find [`state_store`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/kernel/power/main.c#L172) which is where I guess writes will end up.

Comment: Very interesting. I didn't know Ftrace before. Thank you very much.